# When is "en cuisine" used instead of "dans la cuisine"?

Tags: sens, usage

*J'étais **dans la cuisine** et ma sœur étudiait la Bible dans la pièce à côté.*

*J'étais **en cuisine** à préparer ce gateau pour mes amis.*

I guess both phrases mean "in the kitchen". Are they interchangeable in the meaning and can they be swapped in these two sentences without any difference?

Answer (score 6):

They are not interchangeable.

***Dans la cuisine*** is far more frequent and just states "located in **the** kitchen" (**physical** location).

***En cuisine*** means in (**a/the/some**) kitchen, usually a professional one like in a restaurant, but for a reason related to the purpose of the place (**functional** location).

You'll find similar nuances with:

> Le train entre **en** gare / le train entre **dans la** gare.
>
> Je suis arrivé **en** prison / je suis arrivé **à la** prison.