# Se perdre en forêt / dans une forêt

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

*Dans la forêt de Hokkaido* d'Éric Pessan :

> ..., elle ajoute, la voix de nouveau tremblante.

> Je reste sous le choc.

> Enfant, je me suis perdue en forêt.

L'auteur aurait aussi pu écrire "je me suis perdue dans une forêt", n'est-ce pas ? Quelle est la différence entre "se perdre **en** forêt" et se perdre **dans** une forêt" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, *je me suis perdue dans une forêt* est bien sûr aussi possible.

La différence entre ces prépositions tient au niveau d'abstraction

***Dans** une* souligne qu'il y a bien une forêt où ça s'est passé.

***En*** indique qu'il s'agissait **de** forêt mais sans autre précision, peu importe la forêt et il y en avait peut-être plusieurs. Comme l'événement ne s'est probablement produit qu'une seule fois, ***en forêt*** est aussi plus recherché, plus poétique.

Dans certains cas, ***en*** fait partie de locutions comme « *perdu **en mer*** » alors que *perdu **dans la mer*** n'a pas cette valeur.

Dans d'autres cas, ***en*** n'est jamais utilisé : *il s'est perdu **dans** un/le désert/labyrinthe* mais pas *il s'est perdu <s>en désert/labyrinthe</s>*.

Quelques exemples de phrases avec ***en*** : « J'aime faire des randonnées **en montagne** », « Il retourne souvent **en prison** », « Il travaille bien **en classe** »,  « Il s'est perdu **en chemin** », « Il est venu **en train** »...

Référence: *en* ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)) :

> Remarque. Il faut observer que tous ces compléments, le plus souvent indéterminés, ont généralement une valeur nominale très faible. *En* introduit un complément à valeur abstraite par opposition au complément plus concret introduit par *dans*. Avec en l'idée d'intériorité s'est amoindrie au profit d'une sorte d'ambiance. C'est pourquoi *en* est propre à suggérer un état, une situation. Ainsi *en l'air* s'oppose à *dans l'air*; *en classe* à *dans la classe* comme *en prison* à *dans la prison*.

Voir aussi :

[When is "en cuisine" used instead of "dans la cuisine"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36090)

[Quelle est la différence entre les prépositions "dans" et "en" (et "à") ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13647)

Comment: Right -- just like "I'm in the desert" or "the jungle" rather than in a specific desert or jungle on the map.

Comment: @LukeSawczak *perdu en forêt* is going further than *perdu dans une forêt*. It's more like "lost in forest" vs "lost in a forest", if the nuance is not lost in translation ;-)

Comment: Indeed, the pairs seem to be pretty much parallel between French and English. "Lost in the jungle" kind of sounds like "in the middle of a vast, possibly borderless jungle, where I might die..."!

Comment: @LukeSawczak Do you mean "Lost **in** jungle"?

Comment: No, we do we say "lost in **the** jungle", but this is a generic "the jungle" that doesn't refer to any specific jungle. In that sense, it contrasts with "lost in a (particular) jungle", parallel to how "perdu en forêt" contrasts with "perdu dans une forêt". We do this with several environment types: the ocean (which ocean?), the desert (which desert?), the wilderness, the tundra, the prairie. Some are on the edge of being genericizable, such as "the swamp" or "the mountains", but I suspect you'd have to live near such a feature and have that particular one in mind — unlike "the wilderness".

Comment: @LukeSawczak Ah, okay. With *jungle*, we also say *perdu dans la jungle*, never *perdu en jungle*. Are there cases where the English uses *lost **in** <geographic common noun without article>*. I believe *perdu en mer* translates to "lost **at** sea" so the OP *perdue en forêt* would kind of translate to the more than dubious "lost at forest"...

Comment: Neat. Yeah, I think "lost at sea" might be unique. We do say "lost in space" without the article, though I think "space" functions there as a kind of proper noun that we happen not to capitalize...